# Azure WebSites -> Call between two WebAPIs

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core

I have two ASP.NET vNext Web Applications running with CoreCLR on Azure WebSites, published by the lates Visual Studio 2015 CTP.
When I'm trying to make a call from one application to the second with standard HttpClient code:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_webUri);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(request.ToJson(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, contentPost);//.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", request);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                   ...
            }
        }
```

I get following exception:

```
WinHttpException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
   System.Net.Http.WinInetProxyHelper.GetProxyForUrl(SafeInternetHandle sessionHandle, Uri uri, WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO& proxyInfo)

HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
```

my web.config on the azure websites ftp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="kpm-package-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="bootstrapper-version" value="1.0.0-beta2" />
    <add key="kre-package-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="kre-version" value="1.0.0-beta2" />
    <add key="kre-clr" value="CoreCLR" />
    <add key="kre-app-base" value="..\approot\src\Ingrid.Web" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are these `WebRoles` or `Websites`?  What is the format of the `_webUri` that you are passing in?

Comment: @BrendanGreen poster clearly states WebSites not Cloud Services.

Comment: Yes, it's Azure Websites - I have a seperate question on stack overflow about Cloud Services, because there it seems that vnext isn't supported at all at this time on cloud services, at least from VS2015.

Comment: `_webUri` is a standard WebAPI Uri like `http://some.domain/api/controller/action`

Comment: Do you have a default proxy in your web.config?

Comment: No I don't have, I pasted above my web.config

Comment: Have you considered using messaging between your separate apps instead of coupling with direct calls? http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/

Comment: Yes, I had considered ServiceBus, but I have two concerns about it, one is that it's not yet compatible with .NET 5/vnext and I wan't use it to avoid future migrations, second is performance, imho direct calls are faster, and the ServiceBus Relay which is based on WCF seems for me the less performant option than WebAPI direct calls. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution which I found on: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/18

it's better to go with RestSharp than HttpClient, and it is indeed working: http://restsharp.org/